# Android studio - Typing text in the editor searches the editor

Tags: android, android-studio, editor, android-search

When I type something in the editor where code is typed, it goes to the search(ctrl+F) bar. When I click anywhere on the editor, instead of cursor appearing the entire text is selected or the line is selected if the line is empty.

**It works if I restart it**, but happens again. Please help. I don't want to spend most of my programming life restarting android studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just give a chance may help you,

Try to make it default : **reset Android Studio**

**On Windows:**

Go to your User Folder - on Windows 7/8 this would be:

`[SYSDRIVE]:\Users\[your username]` (ex. C:\Users\Amit)

In this folder there should be a folder called `.AndroidStudioBeta or .AndroidStudio`

Delete this folder (take backup of folder).

Comment: are your sure if i delete the main .AndroidStudio.1.5.1 then it's not uninstalled my whole studio ?